# override performfiltering to filter multiple selections

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering

I want to overide a performfiltering so i could filter on multiple selections,

i have searcht google for this, see: [stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734916/2441312)

but there i dont get how i use the answer.

So could some1 help me with this?

ill provide the filtering class(in the array adapter class(below it)) below:

```
public void resetData()
    {
        wines=winesOriginal;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (wineFilter == null){
            wineFilter = new WineFilter();
        }
        return wineFilter;
    }



private class WineFilter extends Filter {


    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence chars) {

        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

        if (chars != null && chars.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Wine> filter = new ArrayList<Wine>();

            String filterString = chars.toString().toLowerCase();

            for (Wine object : wines) {
                object.getBiologic();
                // the filtering itself:
                if (object.getName().toLowerCase().contains(chars.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||object.getColor().toLowerCase().contains(chars.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||object.getCountry().toLowerCase().contains(chars.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||object.getTaste().toLowerCase().contains(chars.toString().toLowerCase())
                        ||String.valueOf(object.getYear()).contains(chars.toString())
                        ||Boolean.valueOf(object.getBiologic().toString().equals(chars.toString().toLowerCase()))
                        ||Boolean.valueOf(object.getSparkling().toString().equals(chars.toString().toLowerCase())))
                    filter.add(object);
            }
            result.count = filter.size();
            result.values = filter;
        } 

        else {
            // add all objects
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = winesOriginal;
                result.count = winesOriginal.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
     protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                     FilterResults results) {

             // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
             if (results.count == 0)
                     notifyDataSetInvalidated();
             else {
                     wines = (List<Wine>) results.values;
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
             }

     }
}
}
```

i was thinking about make the charsequence an array and use that in a for loop with the performfilter but then i got an error about unimplementedcode.

Comment: what is "filter on multiple selections" ?

Comment: that i can filter on wine color and year, with this filter in my code i can do only 1 of those.

i was thinking of a stringarray or a charsequence array and loop trough that?