# how to filter listView, when i don't store my data in an array

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to filter my listView for multiple data, but i don't actually store my data in an array.

it's pulled directly from a .csv file, like this:

```
public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

    TextView mView = (TextView)convertView;

    if(null == mView){
        mView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        mView.setTextSize(28);
    }


    mView.setText(getItem(pos).getItemName());



    return mView;
}

private void loadArrayFromFile(){
    try {

        InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open("menustat.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        //Read each line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            //Split to separate the name from the capital
            String[] RowData = line.split(",");

            //Create a State object for this row's data.
            mealList cur = new mealList();
            cur.setResturant(RowData[0]);
            cur.setFoodCategory(RowData[1]);
            cur.setItemName(RowData[2]);
            cur.setItemDescription(RowData[3]);
            cur.setServingsPerItem(RowData[4]);
            cur.setServingSize(RowData[5]);
            cur.setServingSizeUnit(RowData[6]);
            cur.setCalories(RowData[7]);
            cur.setFat(RowData[8]);
            cur.setSodium(RowData[9]);
            cur.setCarbs(RowData[10]);
            cur.setFiber(RowData[11]);
            cur.setProtein(RowData[12]);

            //Add the State object to the ArrayList (in this case we are the ArrayList).
            this.add(cur);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For reference, this was what i tried doing: [Android - How to filter a listview on multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722444/android-how-to-filter-a-listview-on-multiple-values)

Comment: "i don't actually store my data in an array" -- then what are you storing it in **in memory**? It's nice that you are persisting it in a CSV file, but that is not what your `ListAdapter` is using.

Comment: i get that it's stored somewhere, but i just can't see i stored it in some obvious array the examples i'm looking at are using, is it stored in the csvAdapter file then?

Comment: What "csvAdapter file"? Your own code claims that it is adding data to an `ArrayList` in the one code comment.

Comment: the CSVAdapter is my adapter for the listView where all this code is, and it extends ArrayAdapter, and that's where it puts the data, or am i wrong?

Comment: The first word in `ArrayAdapter` is `Array`. And, if you look at your constructor for your `CSVAdapter`, somewhere, you are supplying an `ArrayList` that is the model being adapted by the adapter.

Comment: i really can't find it, i used the same code as this guy, and would really appreciate if you could help me out: https://github.com/FoamyGuy/CSVListExample

Comment: The sample code that you are using relies upon an `ArrayAdapter` constructor that does not pass in the `ArrayList` to work with. `ArrayAdapter` will create its own `ArrayList` in this case. However, you do not have access to that `ArrayList` to do anything with it, other than by the handful of methods on `ArrayAdapter` that deal with the list (e.g., `getCount()`).

Comment: okay, so back to my original question, how would i then be able to search the listView?

Comment: Here is an example of filtering an `ArrayAdapter` using a `SearchView`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/SearchView